# php mysql-uploading files with the same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am creating an app that upload files in the database. for example i upload 3 files at the same time and i want their IDs to be the same. then i will upload again another batch of files  and their IDs should also be the same but the id is now incremented. \

I am using two IDs DM_ID and id. DM_ID is auto incremented while id is not. I want to get the last value of id. DM_ID and id is in one table.

i tried this code but it is not working

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id from __scannedfiles order by id desc limit 1 ")  OR die(mysqli_error($con));
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $file_id = $row[0];


mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO __scannedfiles VALUES ('','$file_id'+1,'$file_title', '$file_name','$file_pic','$file_deptname','$file_doctype','$file_date','$file_desc')");
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: there is no error message, the id is still not the same for a batch of files.

Comment: have you set auto increment for id?

Comment: Is ID an integer field? Otherwise order won't be as you expect

Comment: @Fabio it is an integer field.

Comment: @Jalpesh id is not auto incremented.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 tables.

One for whatever "batches"
One for files

Both with autoincremented identifier.
Before inserting into files table, insert into batch table, get an id, and then use it for inserts into files table

This way you will have proper identification.

Comment: how can i do that? i am new to php and mysql.

Comment: how can i set the ids to be the same?

Comment: insert into batch table, get an id, and then use it for inserts into files table

Answer (score 0):

At first sight I might think you're inserting a new row with an empty `''` id, which is not permitted. Try specifically stating which attributes you're assigning the values to in the `INSERT` statement.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO __scannedfiles(DM_ID, DM_NANE, DM_PIC, DM_DEPTNAME, DM_DOCTYPE, DM_DATE, DM_DESC) VALUES ('$file_id'+1,'$file_title', '$file_name','$file_pic','$file_deptname','$file_doctype','$file_date','$file_desc')");
```

Comment: the empty '' if for DM_ID which is auto incremented.